# TRANSACTIONS MYSQL LARAVEL

Tags: mysql, laravel, transactions

I have created a store method which stores two step-form that saves data to different tables.  I want a scenario were if a commit fails for any of the tables it should rollback.

CODE

```
public function store()
    {

try{
        $staffrecs = Staffrecord::create([
            'staff_id' => '',
            'first_name' => $this->state['first_name'],
            'middle_name' => $this->state['middle_name'],
            'last_name' => $this->state['last_name'],
            'designation' => $this->state['designation'],
            'grade_level_id' => $this->state['grade_level_id'],
            'phone_number' => $this->state['phone_number'],
            'email' => $this->state['email'],
            'address' => $this->state['address'],
        ]);

        $staffrecs->bankaccount()->create([
            'account_number' => $this->state['account_number'],
            'account_name' => $this->state['account_name'],
            'bank_name' => $this->state['bank_name'],
            'sort_code' => $this->state['sort_code'],
        ]);

        return redirect()->route('dashboard');
}catch (\Exception $e)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply wrap the database operations in [DB Transactions](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/database#database-transactions) in Laravel.
By using this, if one or more operation fails, the whole operations will be automatically rollbacked

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

DB::transaction(function () {
    $staffrecs = Staffrecord::create([
            'staff_id' => '',
            'first_name' => $this->state['first_name'],
            'middle_name' => $this->state['middle_name'],
            'last_name' => $this->state['last_name'],
            'designation' => $this->state['designation'],
            'grade_level_id' => $this->state['grade_level_id'],
            'phone_number' => $this->state['phone_number'],
            'email' => $this->state['email'],
            'address' => $this->state['address'],
        ]);

        $staffrecs->bankaccount()->create([
            'account_number' => $this->state['account_number'],
            'account_name' => $this->state['account_name'],
            'bank_name' => $this->state['bank_name'],
            'sort_code' => $this->state['sort_code'],
        ]);
});

return redirect()->route('dashboard');
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use [transaction](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/database#database-transactions):

If an exception is thrown within the transaction closure, the transaction will automatically be rolled back. If the closure executes successfully, the transaction will automatically be committed.

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

try{
DB::transaction(function () {
     $staffrecs = Staffrecord::create([
            'staff_id' => '',
            'first_name' => $this->state['first_name'],
            'middle_name' => $this->state['middle_name'],
            'last_name' => $this->state['last_name'],
            'designation' => $this->state['designation'],
            'grade_level_id' => $this->state['grade_level_id'],
            'phone_number' => $this->state['phone_number'],
            'email' => $this->state['email'],
            'address' => $this->state['address'],
        ]);

        $staffrecs->bankaccount()->create([
            'account_number' => $this->state['account_number'],
            'account_name' => $this->state['account_name'],
            'bank_name' => $this->state['bank_name'],
            'sort_code' => $this->state['sort_code'],
        ]);
});
 return redirect()->route('dashboard');
}catch (\Exception $e)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add your transaction very easy like below, just add `DB::beginTransaction();` before `try` function and `DB::commit();` after `exception`.

```
public function store()
{
  DB::beginTransaction();
  try{
    $staffrecs = Staffrecord::create([
        'staff_id' => '',
        'first_name' => $this->state['first_name'],
        'middle_name' => $this->state['middle_name'],
        'last_name' => $this->state['last_name'],
        'designation' => $this->state['designation'],
        'grade_level_id' => $this->state['grade_level_id'],
        'phone_number' => $this->state['phone_number'],
        'email' => $this->state['email'],
        'address' => $this->state['address'],
    ]);

    $staffrecs->bankaccount()->create([
        'account_number' => $this->state['account_number'],
        'account_name' => $this->state['account_name'],
        'bank_name' => $this->state['bank_name'],
        'sort_code' => $this->state['sort_code'],
    ]);

    
    }catch (\Exception $e) {
    return false;
   }
   DB::commit();
   return redirect()->route('dashboard');
}
```